# Serve multiple audio files continuously as live stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I want to serve multiple audio files continuously as a live stream, something like an online radio station but I want to stream my own files. The programming language is not important but I prefer PHP or Python.

I did some Google searches and find out that Laravel + Pusher is a good choice but as I know pusher only accepts string data to stream.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Do you intend to make your stream compatible with regular stream clients such as VLC?  Or are you targeting web-based users only?  If web-based, you can simplify your project and lower costs greatly by handling all of the playback and mixing client-side.  Otherwise, you need to build a source client that loads and plays back audio in realtime as PCM, and then sends that off to a codec and then a streaming server.  (FFmpeg is the easiest way to do this, in my opinion.  But, you'll still need to handle playback/mixing in the way you want.)

Comment: @Brad I'm targeting web-based users. Do I need something like Pusher or Socket.io or HTTP is fine? Also, another thing is, How can I send the next file to play from server to clients?

Comment: HTTP is fine.  In this case, you just need a playlist, telling the clients what file to download and play next.

Comment: @Brad thanks, Is there any example on github that I can get the idea? The language doesn’t matter